# Do you need to activate your virtual environment each time you need to use it?

Tags: python

I have managed to create a virtual environment in windows and installed the packages I want to have using pip in the environment (tensorflow). My question is, how do I tell a script I write to use the virtual environment instead of the main form of python on my system?

I know how to activate it using `path/to/venv/Scripts/activate` in the command terminal, but would I have to do this each time before running the script in the terminal? That would be really inconvenient for me since I like to try out the code I write to see if it works (usually doesn't haha) in an IDE (I switch between IDLE and Spyder from Anaconda).

I am a total beginner so if there's a simple solution I porbably just don't know about it, appreciate any help :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) you simply need to activate your virtual environment using the following on Windows:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

This has to be done every time you use it, to save time just keep a Terminal window open.

To leave the virtual environment, deactivate it:

```
.../env/bin/python.exe
```

Comment: Oh okay I think I understand. So even if I am writing a script in Spyder and want to test it, all I have to do is open a terminal and activate the virtual environment there? Then the script im testing in Spyder would use the virtual environment path before the main system?

Comment: @krazzle yes, that is the case

Comment: Sweet, I'll try that in the morning then. Thank you!